# Regex: match 8 character words containing at least 3 instances of a digit or a specific symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches 8 character words that contain at 3 least instances of a digit or the '%' symbol and whitespace after the word.

The following strings should match:

- 'ab1d2f3h '
- 'ab%d2f3h '
- 'ab%d%f3h '
- 'ab%d%f%h '

The regex I have so far looks like this:

```
const string = 'this word ab1d2f3h needs to go, but not this word abcdefgh %%%'.replace(/(?=(?:\D*(\d|%)){3})(\w|%){8}\s/g, '%%%%%%%% ')
```

If I remove '%%%' from the string, it works - 'ab1d2f3h ' is replaced. However, if '%%%' is present in the string, it also replaces 'abcdefhg ', which I don't want to happen.

Does anyone know the proper regex for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a lookbehind assertion is supported in the environment where you are using the pattern:

```
 (?<!\S)(?=\S{8}\s)(?:[^\s\d%]*[%\d]){3}\S*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Positive lookbehind, assert a whitspace boundary to the left
- `(?=\S{8}\s)` positive lookahead, assert 8 non whitespace chars followed by a whitespace char (note that it can also match a newline)
- `(?:[^\s\d%]*[%\d]){3}` Repeat 3 times matching any non whitespace chars except a digit or `%` and then match either a digit or `%`
- `\S*` Match optional non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sdDL2Z/1)

Or using a capture group:

```
(^|\s)(?=\S{8}\s)(?:[^\s\d%]*[%\d]){3}\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uYntfL/1)

In the replacement use the first capture group to keep the leading whitspace char.

```js
const string = 'this word ab1d2f3h needs to go, but not this word abcdefgh %%%'.replace(/(^|\s)(?=\S{8}\s)(?:[^\s\d%]*[%\d]){3}\S*/g, '$1%%%%%%%%')
console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Asked ChatGPT and it answered my question:

You can use the following regular expression to match 8 character words containing at least 3 instances of a digit or the symbol '%':

```
\b(?=(\w*[\d%]){3})\w{8}\b
```

Explanation:

- \b matches a word boundary to ensure that the regex only matches whole words.
- (?=(\w*[\d@]){3}) is a positive lookahead assertion that checks for the presence of at least 3 instances of a digit or the symbol '@' in the word.
- \w{8} matches any 8 word characters (letters, digits, and underscores).
- \b matches the end of the word boundary.

Note that this regex assumes that there are no spaces or other non-word characters in the string. If there are, you may need to modify the regex to handle them.

Comment: Does that mean that the string can not start or end with `%`? That pattern does not really answer the question right? See https://regex101.com/r/LZ1jbO/1

Comment: That's a great point. It should be able to start and/or end with a %, but I realised the chatGPT regex doesn't allow that.

Comment: Try for example this pattern `(?<!\S)(?=\S{8}\s)(?:[^\s\d%]*[%\d]){3}\S*` https://regex101.com/r/85d3xA/1 Or with a capture group `(?:^|\s)((?=\S{8}\s)(?:[^\s\d%]*[%\d]){3}\S*)` https://regex101.com/r/8OoZ2H/1

Comment: Your comment is the correct answer, thank you very much for that!